# Django child model with OneToOne parent does not inherit parent's fields?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-orm

I have a parent classs `Dish` and a child `Pizza` that inherits from `Dish`. They have a 1to1 relationship and I wrote them as follows:

```
class Dish(models.Model):
  PIZZA = 'PIZZA'
  SUB = 'SUB'
  PASTASALAD = 'PASTASALAD'
  PLATTER = 'PLATTER'
  TYPE_CHOICES = ( (PIZZA, 'Pizza'), (SUB, 'Sub'), (PASTASALAD, 'PastaSalad'), (PLATTER, 'Platter') )
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, blank=True)
  size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SIZE_CHOICES, default=SMALL, blank=True)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=None)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name} {self.size} - Price: ${self.price}"

class Pizza(Dish):
  dish = models.OneToOneField(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dish_id_pizza", parent_link=True)
  REGULAR = 'REGULAR'
  SICILIAN = 'SICILIAN'
  STYLE_CHOICES = ( (REGULAR, 'Regular'), (SICILIAN, 'Sicilian'),)
  style = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default=REGULAR)
  topping_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)])

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.size} {self.style} pizza with {self.topping_count} toppings: ${self.price}"
```

Now I have a `Dish` object with ID=17 and a price of 21.95, type=Pizza, size=Small, type=Regular. I now try to create the corresponding `Pizza` object as follows:

```
>>> parent=Dish.objects.get(pk=17)
>>> new_17_pizza = Pizza(dish=parent, topping_count=2, style="Regular")
>>> new_17_pizza.save()
```

I would assume that all `Dish` fields and values are inherited, i.e. I don't have to repeat them, but I get:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_dish.price
```

Why is that? I know I am not allowing `blank=True` for the `price` in `Dish`, but there **IS** already a value of 21.95 stored in the parent dish. Why is 21.95 not inherited? And what is the best/ most elegant way to create these objects here? Or is there a design flaw? THanks and apologies -I'm new to this.

Comment: The error says orders_dish: is there another model you didn't mention?

Comment: I think orders_dish is the ```Dish``` class. It is part of my ```orders``` app in the orders folder where models.py is